# Verification of externally-created ECDSA signatures in Solidity

Tags: signature, ecrecover

I have ECDSA signatures created using Golang without using web3 or anything related to Ethereum, and I want to verify these in Solidity.

**Step 1: Signing the message in Golang**

My Go code to create signatures:

```
import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "crypto/elliptic"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/math"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1"
    "crypto/rand"
    "github.com/miguelmota/go-solidity-sha3"
    "encoding/hex"
    "strconv"
)

func KeyGen() (pubkey []byte, privkey []byte) {
    key, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(S256(), rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    pubkey = elliptic.Marshal(S256(), key.X, key.Y)
    return pubkey, math.PaddedBigBytes(key.D, 32)
}

func Sign(message string, sk []byte) ([]byte) {
    hash := solsha3.SoliditySHA3(solsha3.String("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"+strconv.FormatInt(int64(len(message)),10)+message))
    signature, _ := secp256k1.Sign(hash, sk)
    return signature
}
```

Basically, in the Sign method, I take the hash of

> "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n" + message.length + message

and sign the hash.

My main method is:

```
//Create keypair and signature
pk, sk := KeyGen()
message := "TEST"
sig := Sign(message, sk)

//Print public key and sig in hex notation
fmt.Println("PK", hex.EncodeToString(pk))
fmt.Println("Sig", hex.EncodeToString(sig))

//Print hash
hash := solsha3.SoliditySHA3(solsha3.String("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n"+strconv.FormatInt(int64(len(message)),10)+message))
fmt.Println("hash", hex.EncodeToString(hash[:]))
```

**Step 2: Verification in Solidity**

In Solidity, I use a library by openzeppelin found at https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ECRecovery.sol to recover the public key. I put the three values printed in Go (hash, publickey, signature) as attributes of the contract and attempt to verify the signature:

```
contract ECDSA {

    bytes32 hash = hex"fb96181ff706848b10a93f4028537caf17026e28ce5c0cce90af46b4d3ad04c6";
    bytes sig = hex"cd044278098c2e5e36cc716423638509bbc818b0daadd7b7bba6322a99de67373255201bac6634b6adeb29d4c3bd9b3a6a14363c4e5b5eb3087c7882c7ebca6800";
    bytes publickey = hex"0485d169380f762e82da692c4b50c8873b1ef9820f15ae6cd96d0d4741056a1b9c828f4f027d0374f22311cba8ceb5845232549e6e4df7ae490b6903a5ee1447be";

    function verifysignature() returns (bool)
    {
        return recover(hash, sig) == address(keccak256(publickey));
    }
}
```

**Question**

The above does not return 'true' when given a valid signature. What am I doing wrong?

A few things I think could be wrong:

- Is it even possible to use **ecrecover** to validate signatures that were not created by **web3.eth.sign**?
- Do I use the right prefix for the message before hashing it?
- Is **address(keccak256(publickey))** the right way to convert public key to the corresponding address?

---

**UPDATE**

I created a gist of the full working solution based on the answer by smarx. The gist is found [here](https://gist.github.com/BjornvdLaan/e41d292339bbdebb831d0b976e1804e8).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main issue is that you're signing `"TEST"` but then trying to recover the signer as though you signed a hash of `"\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n4TEST"`.

I'm also not confident you're emitting the public key properly, but you presumably only want the address anyway. Here's some working code:

Go:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/ecdsa"
    "fmt"

    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/hex"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/math"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1"
    "github.com/miguelmota/go-solidity-sha3"
)

func main() {
    key, err := ecdsa.GenerateKey(crypto.S256(), rand.Reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    message := "TEST"
    // Turn the message into a 32-byte hash
    hash := solsha3.SoliditySHA3(solsha3.String(message))
    // Prefix and then hash to mimic behavior of eth_sign
    prefixed := solsha3.SoliditySHA3(solsha3.String("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" + hex.EncodeToString(hash)))
    sig, err := secp256k1.Sign(prefixed, math.PaddedBigBytes(key.D, 32))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("private key:", hex.EncodeToString(math.PaddedBigBytes(key.D, 32)))
    fmt.Println("address:", hex.EncodeToString(crypto.PubkeyToAddress(key.PublicKey).Bytes()))
    fmt.Println("message:", hex.EncodeToString(prefixed))
    fmt.Println("signature:", hex.EncodeToString(sig))
}
```

Solidity (values come from the Go program's output):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract Test {
    function recover(bytes32 hash, bytes sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;
        uint8 v;

        // Check the signature length
        if (sig.length != 65) {
            return (address(0));
        }

        // Divide the signature in r, s and v variables
        // ecrecover takes the signature parameters, and the only way to get them
        // currently is to use assembly.
        // solium-disable-next-line security/no-inline-assembly
        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }

        // Version of signature should be 27 or 28, but 0 and 1 are also possible versions
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }

        // If the version is correct return the signer address
        if (v != 27 && v != 28) {
            return (address(0));
        } else {
            // solium-disable-next-line arg-overflow
            return ecrecover(hash, v, r, s);
        }
    }

    function verifySignature() public pure returns (bool) {
        bytes32 message = 0x2b350a58f723b94ef3992ad0d3046f2398aef2fe117dc3a36737fb29df4a706a;
        bytes memory sig = hex"e6ca6508de09cbb639216743721076bc8beb7bb45e796e0e3422872f9f0fcd362e693be7ca40e2123dd1efaf71ebb94d38052458281ad3b69ec8977c8294928400";
        address addr = 0x8e6a1f13a9c6b9443fea4393291308ac4c965b69;

        return recover(message, sig) == addr;
    }
}
```